# add-apt-repository: unable to execute /usr/bin/add-apt-repository: Too many levels of symbolic links

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, ubuntu-18.04

I am running the below command but it gives an error symbolic paths. Please help me out with this problem.

**Command**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
```

**Traceback**

```
sudo: unable to execute /usr/bin/add-apt-repository: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually, add-apt-repository adds a line to /etc/apt/sources.list or a file  to /etc/apt/sources.list.d directory but a

```
Too many levels of symbolic links
```

Error is actually about the symbolic link structure you have on one of these directories. So in order to find the error you should first find the symbolic link and if there happens to be a cyclic linking (aka. loop link, where A shows B but also B shows A) you should correct it. A better approach is to clean your systems sources lists. But if you have lots of dependencies and outsourced programs I would not recommend it.

```
find -L ./ --mindepth 15
```

can also find cyclic links for you. So you can run it  on the directories you are suspecting. Also, I need to say that this is not the expected behavior of add-apt-repository.

If you have any more details, feel free and obligated to add them.

Comment: Result of the above command: find: unknown predicate `-l'

Comment: My apologies, it should've been "-L" .

Comment: What is the benefit of this command? The process is going on for last two hours

Comment: find -L ./ -mindepth 15. I entered this command

Comment: How to solve this error? I have 100+ symbolic paths

Comment: This command shows the symbolic links and and follows them. So basically what you have here is 100+ symbolic links that points to each other in a chaotic manner. You either need to clear them somehow or get rid of them. But I can not be sure which is healthier. Will look into it.

Comment: How i can get rid of this error?

Comment: For your cycled symbolic links try to backup them and then delete some of them. Maybe this can break the chain. But remember I did not try this.